# How to filter out related strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, levenshtein-distance

I am creating a new aggregator for me. However, I can't figure out how to get rid of similar titles from a list of articles. Here are some examples:

```
Google has officially purchased Fitbit for $2.1 billion
Pixel Watch or not, Fitbit can't save Google's failing Wear OS
Samsung’s latest W series premium device will likely launch this month
Google acquires Fitbit for $2.1 billion, hints at future own-brand wearable
It’s official: Google is buying Fitbit for $2.1 billion
Android 10 rolling out for OnePlus 6T
Google jumps into the wearable space with $2.1 billion acquisition of Fitbit
Google Home app gets a UI refresh and new Cast controls with version 2.15
Google's buying Fitbit: Here's what happens to your Fitbit data
Google Home app 2.15 gets a simpler UI, new media playback cards, and event history
Xiaomi Mi CC9 Pro will be powered by the Snapdragon 730G SoC
Whatsapp implements fingerprint lock for Android
```

Now, as you can see there is a lot of repetition of news about Google acquiring Fitbit. In such cases, I would only like to show the first article on the topic and get rid of the rest.

Ideally, I would like to get the list of articles as close to the one below as possible:

```
Google has officially purchased Fitbit for $2.1 billion
Pixel Watch or not, Fitbit can't save Google's failing Wear OS
Samsung’s latest W series premium device will likely launch this month
Android 10 rolling out for OnePlus 6T
Google Home app gets a UI refresh and new Cast controls with version 2.15
Google's buying Fitbit: Here's what happens to your Fitbit data
Xiaomi Mi CC9 Pro will be powered by the Snapdragon 730G SoC
Whatsapp implements fingerprint lock for Android
```

Note that the News about `Google Home` was also repeated twice. So, it was also removed from the list.

It looks like I could use `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()` functions to determine the similarity of two strings. I looped through the titles and used `levenshtein($previous_title, $current_title)` to calculate the distance. Here are some of my results which show that I can't rely on these functions:

```
Google to bring Pixel 4 voice Recorder app to older Pixels | Xiaomi Mi CC9 Pro will be powered by the Snapdragon 730G SoC = 50
It’s official: Google is buying Fitbit for $2.1 billion | Google acquires Fitbit for $2.1 billion, hints at future own-brand wearable = 58
```

The titles in first case are about different topics but there Levenshtein distance is still less than the second combination where the titles are about the same topic.

How can I get more accurate results while filtering out similar titles?

Thanks.